# Swiftのメソッドの自然言語文中での表記法

Tags: swift

自然言語文中にメソッド名を記述するときに、Objective-Cでは+[Foo bar]や-[Foo baz:qux:]の様に書いたと思いますが、Swiftではどのように書くのが一般的でしょうか？

Comment: 「文中」とは、なんの文のことですか？それと、その文がなんであっても、`+[Foo bar]`や`-[Foo baz:qux:]`とは記述しませんね。

Comment: @Harawo スタックトレースを見られた事はないですか？例えば`-[FBSession closeAndClearTokenInformation]`と出力されます。stackoverflowでの質問でも'-[UIView initWithFrame:] returning nil' http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26190372/uiview-initwithframe-returning-nil のように利用されていますね。18年くらいObjective-Cを触ってますが、一般的な記述形式だと思います。文中というのが分かりにくかったですね。自然言語文中です。質問を編集しました。

Comment: 18年はすごいですね。OpenStepの頃から馴染んでいらっしゃったんですか。これは大変失礼いたしました。

Comment: 自然言語中ということで、Class Referenceの表記が「一般的」になると思うのですが、しかし例えば[`NSObject`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSObject_Class/index.html)を見ると、クラスメソッドもインスタンスメソッドも区別せず`load()`表記になりますが、**see also** では`– load`表記とブレていますね。

Answer (score 5):

Rubyだとインスタンスメソッドは`Range#each`のように「#」で繋いで書き、クラスメソッドは`Range.new`のように「.」で繋いで書きます。このようなドキュメントや本を書く上で標準化された表記法のルールがあるか、という質問ですよね？

Objective-Cでは`+[Foo bar]`や`-[Foo baz:qux:]`のように「+」と「-」で区別し、あるいは文脈でレシーバが明らかなら、`-objectsForKeys:notFoundMarker:`などと書くのが慣例的に行われてきたと思います。

Swiftは今のところはっきりと決まったものは無いと思います。

強いていえば単体のメソッドやfunctionはアップルのドキュメントに倣って`drawRect(_:)`のように書いている本やサイトが多いと思います。

Rubyのようにクラスメソッドとインスタンスメソッド（あるいはStaticメソッド）をうまく区別する表記法は無くて、区別なく`Array.append(_:)`のように単にドットで繋げて書いていることが多数のようです。

Answer (score 1):

Swiftではありませんが、Javaはドキュメント中で`ClassName.methodName()`と表記することが正式となっています。オーバーロードを区別するための引数リストは`ClassName.methodName(Type1, Type2, ...)`のように型名のみだったり、`ClassName.methodName(Type1 arg1, Type2 arg2, ...)`のようにパラメータ名を含めたりすることもあります。静的メソッド（クラスメソッド）と非静的メソッド（インスタンスメソッド）で区別する記法はありません。

- [javadoc - Java API ドキュメントジェネレータ](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/jp/1.5.0/tooldocs/windows/javadoc.html#@see)

Javadoc形式のコメント内では`ClassName#methodName()`と表記しますが、ドキュメントジェネレータに処理させた結果として出力される文書では、`#`は`.`に置換されるようになっています。
※個人のブログ記事などでは文章中でも`ClassName#methodName()`と表記されていることが多いですが、おそらくJavadoc中の表記をそのまま（間違って）使っているのだと思われます。

C#も`ClassName.MethodName()`の形式です。

- [<see> - C# プログラミング ガイド | Microsoft Docs](https://docs.microsoft.com/ja-jp/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/xmldoc/see)

C++はスコープ解決演算子`::`を使った`ClassName::MemberFuncName()`の形式です。規格書にも頻出します。

- [ISO/IEC 14882:2014, N3797 (draft)](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2013/n3797.pdf)

Answer (score 0):

私自身は、「自然言語文中」にこのような表記はしたことないですが、質問者さんのおっしゃる「スタックトレース」中では、下図のように、Swift環境では表示されます。

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

クラスメソッドは、`static Hoge.fuga() -> ()`とあるように、`static`で、インスタンスメソッドと区別するようです。

Comment: staticを付けてるんですね。文中に書くには冗長ですよね。Javaとか他言語がどうしているのか気になってきました。